# using multiple threads simultaneously c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2015

I'm having issues with using multiple threads for my madelbrot program.

One of the ways I tired following a tutorial

```
    int sliceSize = 800 / threads;
    double start = 0, end = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    {
        start = i * sliceSize;
        end = ((1 + i) * sliceSize);

        thrd.push_back(thread(compute_mandelbrot, left, right, top, bottom, start, end));

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    {
        thrd[i].join();
    }
    thrd.clear();
```

but the code takes only half the time to compute, while using 8 threads.

I also tried something more complicated but it doesn't work at all

```
void slicer(double left, double right, double top, double bottom)
{
    /*promise<int> prom;
    future<int> fut = prom.get_future();*/


    int test = -1;
    double start = 0, end = 0;
    const size_t nthreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); //detect how many threads cpu has
    {
        int sliceSize = 800 / nthreads;

        std::cout << "CPU has " << nthreads << " threads" << std::endl;
        std::vector<std::thread> threads(nthreads);

        for (int t = 0; t < nthreads; t++)
        {

            threads[t] = std::thread(std::bind(
                [&]()
            {

                mutex2.lock();
                test++;

                start = (test) * sliceSize;
                end = ((test + 1) * sliceSize);

                mutex2.unlock();

                compute_mandelbrot(left, right, top, bottom, start, end);


            }));
        }
        std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), [](std::thread& x) {x.join(); }); //join threads
    }
}
```

but it seems while it is computing 8 things at once they tend to over lap even after using a mutex, and it's not any faster.

This has given me a headache for the last 7h and I want to kill myself. Help.

Comment: Threads aren't always cheap and if there is resource competition in `compute_mandelbrot` 50% might be the best you can do. Could we have a [mcve] that better describes the issue?

Comment: Try using fewer threads.  How many cores does your CPU have?  Use that many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot at play when you're trying to speed up a workload by multi-threading, and in the perfect world it's pretty much impossible to get an Nx speed-up when multiplying by N threads. Some things to bear in mind:

1. If you're making use of hyperthreading (so using 1 thread per virtual core on the system, not just per physical core), then you don't get the equivalent performance of 2 real cores - you'll get some percentage (probably around 1.2x or so).
2. The operating system (Windows) is going to be doing stuff while your workloads are executing. It's fairly random what and when these OS tasks cut into your app time, but it's going to make a difference. Always expect some percentage of your CPU time is going to be stolen by windows.
3. Any kind of synchronization is going to heavily impact performance. In your second example, mutexes are pretty hefty and are likely going to impact performance.
4. Memory accesses, cache access, etc, are going to come in to play. Multiple threads accessing memory all over the place is going to result in pressure on the cache, which is going to have a (potential) impact.

I'm curious - what sort of times are you looking at here? And how many iterations are you passing on each thread? To dig in and see what's happening timing-wise, you could try something like recording the start/end time of each thread using queryPerformanceCounter to see how long each is running, when they start, etc. Posting the times here for 1, 2, 4 and 8 threads would maybe shed a little light.

Hopefully this at least helps a little...

Comment: I believe I'm not using it right. When I'm using the code from first example my mandlerbot computes 2x faster, but when I use a more advanced madlerbot code it actually slows it down.

Comment: 8 threads: `500ms;` 4: `900ms;` 2: `1500ms;` 1: `1900ms;` , I know you should be able to get faster results, like with the other code I posted, but there are different issues with it I can't always get everything working

Comment: Those timing numbers actually look pretty good - almost 4x more time between 1 and 8 threads. Are those times sums of individual thread execution times or total program time? If the latter, I’m not sure you’d expect to get much better than that.